# callback for player.sendEvent() in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Is there any way to add callback function for 
player.sendEvent() in jwplayer.

```
function timeseek(obj){
        seek_position = obj.position ;
        player.sendEvent('PLAY',false);//pause video
        updateT(logid,seek_position,1);//update db with current paused value
        player.sendEvent('SEEK ',seek_position);//seek to position
        player.sendEvent('PLAY',true);//Play video
            }
```

i want to do actions in above function one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a JWPlayer expert, however, if I understand the question correctly, and my assumption is correct on what sendEvent is doing, then I would try the following:

```
player.onPlay(function(e) {
  // do something...
});

player.onSeek(function(e) {
   // do something
});
```

Because JWPlayer is event driven, you can listen for events and state changes, when something happens that you care about, you react in your event handler. If you explain exactly what you want to do after specific events, I can provide a more concrete example.

See [JWPlayer Events Documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16024/listening-for-player-events) for more information.

Comment: i am working on video analytics now, i am constantly updating ending position after regular intervals. Based on starting and ending position i am updating the duration. The problem is when a seek is done i am first pausing the video at current position then updating the db with ending position and then seeking the video to user requested position and playing the video again. so the problem is in the function mentioned above everything done at a time , i need to have those events executed one after the other.